# Can we display more than one property from the geo.json file in the ToolTips in Echarts maps?

Tags: angular, geojson, echarts

I am implementing Apache echarts maps in my angular application. The '.geo.json' file I use to import the map has two properties in the properties array of the geo.json file. One is the 'name' and the other is 'code'.

I am mapping each data against the 'name' property. The data is displayed as expected: 'Name - value' in the tooltip. Is there a way to add additional information on the tooltip like 'Name (Code) - value' where the code comes from the property in the geo.json file.

Here is extract of the code,

// mymap.geo.json extract

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [3.172704445659,50.011996744997], [3.1821975358417,50.012335988197], [3.2174797791605,50.023182479597], [3.230541907493,50.031311385584]...
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "code": "02",
        "name": "Aisne"
      }
    },
```

// component.ts file

```
mapFunction(chartData: ObjectType[]): void {

    // @ts-ignore
    echarts.registerMap('franceByDepartment', franceMap);
    
    this.chartOptionsMap = {
      series: [
        {
          type: 'map',
          name: 'May By Departments',
          colorBy: 'series',
          map: 'franceByDepartment',
          roam: true,
          nameProperty: 'name',
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
          selectedMode: false,
          data: chartData.map(res => ({
            name: res.department,
            value: res.countOfData,
          }))
        },
      ],
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        showDelay: 0,
        transitionDuration: 0.2,
        formatter: 'Department name : {b} <br/> Code:  <br/> Count : {c}'
      },
      visualMap: {
        left: 'right',
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        inRange: {
          color: [
            '#313695',
            '#4575b4',
            '#74add1',
            '#abd9e9',
            '#f46d43',
            '#d73027',
          ]
        },
        text: ['High', 'Low'],
        calculable: true
      },
      toolbox: {
        show: true,
        //orient: 'vertical',
        left: 'left',
        top: 'top',
        feature: {
          dataView: { readOnly: false },
          restore: {},
          saveAsImage: {}
        }
      },
    };
  }
```

[image: The tooltip generated]

The default property the map uses to map is the 'name'
By changing the value to
`nameProperty: 'name',` to `nameProperty: 'code',`

The value shown will be the code, but is there a way to include both values from the geo.json file in the tooltip?

I tried to fetch the properties like this

```
let p = mymap.features[0].properties.code;
```

But I get the error

```
Should not import the named export 'features'.'0'.'properties'.'code' (imported as 'mymap') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
```

### Solutions tried

As suggested I updated the tooltip code with the following

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function (params) {
          const district = france.features.find(
            (district) => district.properties.nom === params.name
          );
          console.log(district);
          return district.properties.code + ' ' + district.properties.nom;
        },
      },
```

However this returns the following error,

ERROR in ./src/app/statistics/statistics.component.ts 43:29-49
export 'features'.'find' (imported as 'france') was not found in '/src/assets/france-geo.json' (possible exports: 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 3, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 4, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 5, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 6, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 7, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 8, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 9, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95)

ERROR
src/app/statistics/statistics.component.ts:48:18 - error TS7006: Parameter 'district' implicitly has an 'any' type.

48                 (district) => district.properties.nom === params.name

---

Please find the [stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstatistics%2Fstatistics.component.ts)
with the solution applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [formatter function](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-map.tooltip.formatter) to log the the given arguments to the console and take a look at their structure and return anything you want:

```js
option = {
    tooltip: {},
    ...
    series: [
        {
            ...
            tooltip: {formatter: someFunction},
        },
    ...
    ]
}

function someFunction(params) {
    console.log(params);
    return params.data;

}
```

Here is a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMgL4A0asAHgIIUQDOhq66YAniAKaEDkAxgIZgOAc2AAnVtzLNYAE0H9CAbW4BZGFNjcAKgFcOm7gHUOsw9oAWuwwDExEQwGVBT3dG4BdcqXKsa9RnIWdi4tADd-bH1ub2lYOg57DgZYJSDkdPR5MEVUgEYAVgAGElgAJgBmEvKygBZSsryADlK8ioLW2oB2BoA2Io84mUwcPEYAM3EAW0EhMUI6YCmOGzdeHxlgzh5sCGgDdKJyLyIAbhQUcbXIGHillbWAChB-MX4pugBKDPReGEXsBwAHTYYDCZ6vd5fc5EIA).

Here is another small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=DYUwLgBAZgTghgOwMYgNwCh1wM4E9nQCuyYAlgPYLThIAWA4iOQFLaUAUAlBAN7oQQklbJBghsAB2EgIAXghwA7nFKQoNWu34CIAclpgwE7AC4A9GdiIUAWgDmTAFZsEAOjti75UmIAmcADdSX1dYMzEpM18QCTgYMBAAWxAEMGx3JxddbU4MAStkGXklFVFxKQRsEFdnDlztEDo4tNdPUhEQGABZOAl2XQKUACFcABEY5uTU3QAaaHhCuYGFlF16gF9MdTA6RhYXLgxyCTJKOV5tATBycmAyCRNedZnLiCqYUnFHgG1XgT4dICIGBcBIQI9dIlerM_jpghDjp04NcYNgRuNYvEpmAYUCdEJgOQYCMIe9PthcXiIFCHnpBiB0RMsSkcS8qRAYOQ4IlHmAYIQQGyqQhuSAAAqcsHxXAQhDkRKUvHAOAAIxAwEeAPZb1o5EUjygcGAVVhAmepogytw5EIYAAwizOj9dABWAAMAFJZnp3V6ALpCpVwa22gDKpAAXuCIC73YGgVVQEgEr4uuRogajVV44D_GA4D8Lf8ICLkhCAIKkBDegJGgWPACMLog5u1vBLoor7QQIBrdejDYATC2c0CeB2y3p6D5KNE-8B6xAAJwti0Bi3XW73TVF6BEqGGJ1EEgUKjsTHc7DcLVtoSVSC-dp80jJ8700IgZGEMTpKBV3zsOwj4iB8ybcLIAB8EDAc-yauBIkqdGQ4iuHKiRyLI8gXok6SliA9RtgId5sKAriEnYQFPqBYCcLuAhiGA35UDB1HwYh8Tkq4QjRBAADUEAAESCXx0FUS-YBsYiHEoWheTaps7IKUCSkCH62jrKgQA) which may help.

Comment: This solution gives me access to the three variables 'seriesName', 'name' and 'value' But it does not allow me to access the additional properties from the geojson file

Comment: Are you not able to retrieve the desired information with the data given by the formatter function? If you would provide a minimal working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple) it would be easier to help.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetwp?file=package.json  -  This is the link to the stackblitz sample project.

I've added some sample data, wondering if we can include an additional value in the tooltip with the code found in the france-geo.json file
properties": {
        "code": "02",
        "name": "Aisne"

Comment: updated my answer with another example. take a look

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws an error. I've updated the error under the 'Solutions tried' subheader and updated the stackblitz project under the assumption that the way you import the france map does not matter and still returns a .json as input

Comment: This seems to be a typescript error. You could try to not enforce [strict type checking](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-fix-to-typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type/) or include [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) in the formatter function: `if ("properties" in district) {..}`

Comment: Thank you so much, Matthias. This made it very clear.  The issue here was the way I import the geoJson file. Modifying it from,

`import * as france from '/src/assets/france-geo.json';`

to 

`import france from '/src/assets/france-geo.json';`

helped resolve the issue.